# How to draw a line between the widgets in Qscrollarea using pyqt4

Tags: python-2.7, pyqt4

Here is my code i created  multiple widget in qscrollarea. In between the each widget i want to draw a line.Can any one please tell me how can i draw line in between the each widget of the scroll area.

```
        self.mainw = QtGui.QWidget()

        self.scrollArea_left.setWidget(self.mainw)
        self.ordersvbox = QtGui.QGridLayout(self.mainw)
        self.w1 = QtGui.QWidget()
        self.v1 = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(spacing=0)
        self.v1.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.w1.setLayout(self.v1)
        self.h1 = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
        self.l1 = QtGui.QLabel("#A")
        self.lprogress = QtGui.QLabel("Porgress")
        self.lamount = QtGui.QLabel("200 Rs")
        self.items_count = QtGui.QLabel("2 items")
        self.h1.addWidget(self.l1)
        self.h1.addWidget(self.lprogress)
        self.h1.addWidget(self.lamount)
        self.v1.addLayout(self.h1)
        self.v1.addWidget(self.items_count)
        self.ordersvbox.addWidget(self.w1,0,0)

        self.w2 = QtGui.QWidget()
        self.v2 = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self.w2)
        self.h2 = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
        self.l2 = QtGui.QLabel("#B")
        self.lprogress2 = QtGui.QLabel("x")
        self.lamount2 = QtGui.QLabel("300 RS")
        self.items_count2 = QtGui.QLabel(" 2 items")
        self.h2.addWidget(self.l2)
        self.h2.addWidget(self.lprogress2)
        self.h2.addWidget(self.lamount2)
        self.v2.addLayout(self.h2)
        self.v2.addWidget(self.items_count2)
        self.ordersvbox.addWidget(self.w2,1,0)

        self.w3 = QtGui.QWidget()
        self.v3 = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self.w3)
        self.h3 = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
        self.l3 = QtGui.QLabel("#C")
        self.lprogress3 = QtGui.QLabel("z")
        self.lamount3 = QtGui.QLabel("200 RS")
        self.items_count3 = QtGui.QLabel(" 2 items")
        self.h3.addWidget(self.l3)
        self.h3.addWidget(self.lprogress3)
        self.h3.addWidget(self.lamount3)
        self.v3.addLayout(self.h3)
        self.v3.addWidget(self.items_count3)
        self.ordersvbox.addWidget(self.w3,2,0)
```

Comment: `line = QFrame(); line.setFrameShape(QFrame.HLine)`. (See: [docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qframe.html#Shape-enum)).

Comment: sir  i want use many hline in my programe evary time i dont want to write these two line can you please tell me i want to initialise one time only  after that  i want to use multiple times

Comment: Just create your own sublass of `QFrame`.

Comment: Thank you sir , i have one more doubt if  you knew can u please help me